# Trying to Dampen a Boosted LC Circuit

Tags: power-electronics, boost, resonance, resonant-converter, sinusoidal

I am currently implementing the circuit shown below where the first stage is a boost converter and the second stage (output stage) is an LC circuit with a boost topology. The goal is to take a 24V DC input and produce a sinusoidal output with a peak-to-peak measurement of 80V. The circuit in the image was taken from a [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/cn/AppNotes/cn587413.pdf) where an output of 40Vpp was achieved. In order to reach the 80Vpp output, I have changed L1 to be 82uH.

The issue I am currently experiencing is that my output stage is resonating too much. I am able to hit well over 150Vpp with my boost converter only at a 4% duty cycle. I would like my output to be adjusted to 80Vpp by changing the boost stage duty cycle.

Any ideas on to how I can dampen the output would be appreciated. So far, I have not changed any of the components in the output stage because I need to connect a piezoelectric disk which has a resonance frequency of 117kHz. This circuit has already been optimized for that disk so I left it unchanged.

[image]

Comment: Loading the output and/or reducing the input voltage could reduce the output pk-pk voltage. Also, I can see a peak voltage detector circuit. Maybe use that as a feedback to the control circuit to limit the o/p to 80Vpp?

Comment: Get a simulator (free) and simulate. No point asking until you get to grips with a simulation.

Comment: Try lowering \$\sqrt{L/C}\$  because \$ Q = \dfrac{\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}}{R}\$

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth My input voltage is set at 24V, the current and peak voltage feedback is for frequency sweeping. When I connect a piezo at the output I need to sweep the frequency and the frequency where the current is the greatest will then be used since that is the frequency where the piezo resonates best.

Comment: @Andyaka I have simulated the circuit in PLECs. It is working as expected however I am not sure what I need to change to dampen the resonance.

Comment: Embed your simulation schematic please.